# c# - how to change button image on all my forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got three forms and on one of them there is a combobox which is supposed to change icons on all my running forms and images of buttons located on another forms, when selected value of the combobox is changed.

Please note that the problem is solved when it comes to changing icons, but I need solution for changing buttons images. I have managed to do so on just one form (where the combobox is located). I cannot figure out how to customise buttons on other forms as well.

I have tried this way:

```
    private void combo_Theme_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main f1 = new Main();
        if (combo_Theme.Text == "Purple")
        {
            foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
            {
                form.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
                f1.btn_Exit.Image = Properties.Resources.EXIT_purple;
            }
        }
```

... but had no success.

Basically, I am stuck now, since the code above doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Why you change btn_Exit.Image inside foreach loop?

Comment: I have tried outside the loop it didn't work as well. By "didn't work", I mean nothing happened.

Comment: Nothing happened in forms icon or buttons icon? To change button image of all buttons (inside every form) you have to cycle through form's controls (in a recursive way) to pick OfType<Button>(). There is somewhere here on SO a similar question.

Comment: As I said, it changes icons perfectly, but the problem is I cannot change buttons, except the one which has the same location as the combobox which is used for changing. Anyway, I am quite new to c#, so I would be very grateful if you explained this to me further, since I cannot do it myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imagine to cycle each button with form.Controls.OfType<Button>(). This will work with button that are children of a form (so, for example, it won't work if they're inside a panel). That's why I said you have to make it recursive (search here on SO). Then you have to _understand_ which button must be updated...That said I wouldn't do in that way, I would make each form reactive to a global event "ThemeChanged".

Comment: I can see where are you coming from. However, that is much more complex than I can take it right now, since the fact I am still a beginner. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-design your forms by implementing some interface with some method, calling that method will actually update the images of the buttons on a specific form. That way you don't have to loop through each controls (in nested relationship) and check out every button. However if your forms don't have complex nested relationship and the number of buttons is small, we can use the following code, in fact this code still works OK (responsive enough) when you have thousands of controls on a form with several nested containers):

```
public IEnumerable<Button> GetAllButtons(Form form){
  Stack<Control> controls = new Stack<Control>();
  controls.Push(form);
  while(controls.Count > 0){
    var control = controls.Pop();
    foreach(var c in control.Controls){
      if(c is Button) yield return c;
      controls.Push(c);
    }
  }
}
//now use that method in your code like this:
private void combo_Theme_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Main f1 = new Main();
    if (combo_Theme.Text == "Purple")
    {
        foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
        {
            form.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
            f1.btn_Exit.Image = Properties.Resources.EXIT_purple;
            //looping through each button on the current form
            foreach(var button in GetAllButtons(form)){
              //your code here
              button.Image = Properties.Resources.EXIT_purple;
            }
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My form is pretty simple and the code which user **Precious Tijesunimi** provided works fine for me. However, I can see where are you coming from and your code would definitely be better solution if my form was more complex.

Comment: @ExintaEnea yes, even your forms has hundreds of controls with some nested containers, it still works.